# AWS Elastic Beanstalk delete the database volume in every deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, volumes

I am uploading the .yml multicontainer file to EB from the AWS console and everything works fine the fist time, but next time I deploy the same .yml EB start a new mySql database, it seems that doesn't detect the volumes. Any ideas? Thanks!

**Here my .yml file:**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7.25
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=testpass
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
    container_name: local_database
    ports: 
     - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
     - './mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql'


  nest:
    image: rsteercen/nest_local:latest
    container_name: nest
    command: sh -c "sleep 10 && npm run migrations:run && node dist/src/main" 
    environment:
     - DATABASE_TYPE=mysql
     - DATABASE_HOST=local_database
     - DATABASE_PORT=3306
     - PORT=3000
     - DATABASE_USER=root
     - DATABASE_PASS=testpass
     - DATABASE_NAME=testdb

    ports: 
     - '80:3000'
    depends_on:
      - database
```

Answer (score 1):

How is your volume defined?
If you're just using docker-compose, you should define also the volume there, fe. like:

```
volumes:
  db-data:
    driver_opts:
        lifecycle_policy: AFTER_30_DAYS
```

and then attach it to the service:

```
services:
  database:
    volumes:
     - db-data:/mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!  and it’s a important that the volumes definition be before the services 